# What is the projection matrix of A onto its row space, if A is $\mathbb{R^{m*n}}$ with linearly independent rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, projection-matrices

I know that the projection matrix of A onto its column space, if A is $\mathbb{R^{m*n}}$ with linearly independent columns is $P=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$
 Does this follow for the projection matrix of A onto its row space, if A is $\mathbb{R^{m*n}}$ with linearly independent rows

Comment: What turns the row space of a matrix into column space?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin - when we take the transpose of A?. So $P=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}Ab$?

Comment: Yup. That's how you do it. :)